# Windows web server randomly crashes, how can I see state and what processes were running?

Tags: asp.net, windows-2003-webserver

I have a windows 2003 server that randomly seems to crash.

How to debug this?

It is win 2003 running an Asp.net website.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Debug Diagnostics Tool**.

> When an IIS process that hosts a Web application stops unexpectedly, the system unloads the process, and all running requests are lost. To troubleshoot this scenario, you can use the Debug Diagnostic tool.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919789

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=28bd5941-c458-46f1-b24d-f60151d875a3&DisplayLang=en